# iOS - Unicode numeric value of individual characters in a string

Tags: ios, unicode, character-encoding, numeric

For Objective-C in iOS:

If I have a string how could I read the unicode numeric value of an individual character?

For example if my string was: "∆" That unicode character is U+0394, so how could I read the string, figure out the "0394" then create a new string with say 100 added to that value, so the new string would be the character U+0494 or "ҕ"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is a fallacy in your logic. `∆ + 100 != ҕ`. Unicode is evaluated in base-16 (hex), so '∆' is actually equal to `916` in decimal, not `394`. Thus, `0x0494 - 0x0394 = 0x0100`, which equals `256`.

With that in mind, your code should look something like this:

```
unichar delta = 0x0394;
unichar weirdB = delta + 0x0100;

NSString *deltaStr = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&delta length:1];
NSString *weirdBString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&weirdB length:1];
```

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw thanks, but please don't use the code @zahreelay provided. it is incorrect and WILL NOT WORK!. `-intValue` does not return the correct value for a unicode character. Please keep that in mind and change the accepted answer while you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
  NSString *c = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", unicodeValue];
  int unicode = [c intvalue];
  // then create a new one
  unicode+=100;
  // create a unicode value again
  NSString *uniString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:(unichar *)&unicode length:1];
```

Comment: Major fallacy in your logic. Unicode is base 16, not base 10.

Comment: whatevr is the base, how does that affect this answer??

Comment: Thankyou for your answer! And thank you Richard for pointing out the base issue! I wasn't aware :) I guess I want to add "64" then ;) Haha!

Comment: Learn basic computing. Wikipedia is your friend: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal. Also, your code is wrong. #1, it should be `-intValue`, not `-intvalue`. Second of all, `-intValue` returns zero on a character that is not numeric `'0' - '9'`. Finally, take the time to read my answer and explain how the OP is incorrect, before just down voting it. Downvotes should be reserved for incorrect answers, not being mad at me for show you your answer is incorrect.

Comment: Please please please don't take this the wrong way, but THIS CODE DOESN'T WORK! `-intValue` doesn't work on a unicode character!

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII thanks for pointing out, not using a compiler, would never have have noticed, unless you pointed out, upvoted again