# how to convert unicode to nstring?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, unicode

I have to convert unicode char to NSString 
the text i have to convert is   doc.title = "hello 64 **\U00bf** world sample"
my code is:

```
UILabel *lblName=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, 250, 88)];
            const char *cString = [doc.title UTF8String];//where doc.title is above text
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cString length:strlen(cString)];
            NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            lblName.text= string;
            NSLog(@"Title is = %@ \n",doc.title);
            lblName.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
            lblName.numberOfLines=100;
            lblName.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
            lblName.textColor=[UIColor  colorWithRed:2.0/255.0 green:104.0/255.0 blue:170.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblName];
            [lblName release];
```

where am i doing wrong?
Tried the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567598/ios-unicode-numeric-value-of-individual-characters-in-a-string) but could not get it right.

Answer (score 0):

```
+(NSString *)getTextFromChar:(unichar)character
{
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",character];
    return string;
}
```

Pass your cString to this method

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
char *cString[] = [doc.title UTF8String];//where doc.title is above text
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:cString length:strlen(cString)];
            NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            lblName.text= string;
```

or simply call

```
-[NSString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES].
```

Comment: it printed  "hello 64 ¿  world sample" instead of "hello 64 — world sample"

Comment: u002D is for - hyphen minus not this u00bf